# laravel change find by id to find by customerid

Tags: php, laravel

laravels authentication system uses Id by default ,but lets say you have a bigger database with many tables how do you specify lets say the customer table

```php
$user = User::where('name', '=', $name);

if($user->count()) {
    $user=$user->first();

    $user->status= 'super';

    if($user->save()) {
        return Redirect::route('home')
    }

}
```

Comment: You use the Customer model instead of the User model? Unclear what you're asking.... do you want to search by customerid in the User table, do you want to search in a different table?

Comment: I only have one model ,The user model and that is set up to the customer table .Basically I need it to search by customer id not by id.At the moment in the database it has to be named id for the code to work but i want to call the field in myphpadmin customerid.thank you for any help you can give me with this I am sorry if my explanations aren't great.

Comment: Why do you have a `customer_id` and an `id` in your Customer table: explain the logic behind this? what's the difference between `id` and `customer_id`?

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I have received my answer by another user, there was'nt customer id and id there was only id and I wanted that field not to be named id ,I wanted it to be called customerID thanks for your help though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your primary key is named differently than `id` you can configure the column name in the model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';

}
```

It's all in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage):

> **Note:** Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a `primaryKey` property to override this convention. Likewise, you may define a connection property to override the name of the database `connection` that should be used when utilizing the model.